# Select & display odd numbered indexes from the list of numbers in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, indexer

I am trying to achieve the indexes in the following manner:

```
[1,3,5,7,9,11...],
[2,4,6,8,10,12,...],
[3,5,7,9,11,13...],
[4,6,8,10,12,14,..],
```

So far I've achieved the format as:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,...],
2,3,4,5,6,7...]
3,4,5,6,7,8...],
```

using the CODE LINE

```
indexer = np.arange(3)[None,:] + np.arange(8)[:,None]
```

I am not sure how to achieve desired results.

Kindly help me with this!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a step size for `np.arange` in the following way `np.arange(start, stop, step)`:

```py
>>> np.arange(1, 12, 2)[None,:] + np.arange(4)[:,None]
array([[ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12],
       [ 3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13],
       [ 4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can u help me in the following part as well? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62894496/6842793