# Plots obtained via Matplotlib for each row of a 2D array againt their indices are not correct

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, indexer, line-plot

Below is the code that I wrote for some project.
The plots are not correct which I'm obtaining via matplotlib.
It would be very helpful, If I can know where am I doing wrong?

```
randomFL =[]
for i in range(0,100):
    x = round(random.uniform(0.1, 10.1),2)
    randomFL.append(x)

indexer = np.arange(10)[None, :] + np.arange(8)[:, None]

a=np.array(randomFL)

xyz=a[indexer]

print(randomFL)

[2.84, 5.03, 3.67, 3.65, 9.61, 8.76, 3.18, 8.12, 7.95, 0.36, 4.16, 8.44, 9.99, 0.44, 5.24, 4.5, 9.63, 6.75, 1.82, 6.14, 0.92, 8.02, 8.08, 6.57, 4.93, 2.96, 5.18, 1.55, 0.74, 6.64, 6.57, 8.96, 8.3, 3.04, 3.5, 3.94, 8.42, 0.45, 8.63, 6.09, 8.2, 0.93, 7.48, 6.73, 7.09, 4.88, 9.14, 5.33, 3.4, 9.45, 2.15, 8.54, 7.08, 8.25, 9.9, 0.43, 7.74, 9.56, 8.98, 2.24, 1.54, 0.93, 9.56, 9.08, 6.62, 4.71, 4.08, 0.63, 2.48, 8.34, 2.24, 5.67, 9.97, 7.92, 6.23, 7.76, 2.89, 0.8, 3.18, 7.9, 7.49, 5.54, 8.44, 0.13, 8.31, 6.21, 2.43, 10.02, 8.38, 1.93, 6.79, 5.28, 7.35, 2.23, 6.16, 9.04, 5.57, 2.7, 2.22, 4.4]

print(indexer)


[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
 [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
 [ 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]]

print(xyz)


[[2.84 5.03 3.67 3.65 9.61 8.76 3.18 8.12 7.95 0.36]
 [5.03 3.67 3.65 9.61 8.76 3.18 8.12 7.95 0.36 4.16]
 [3.67 3.65 9.61 8.76 3.18 8.12 7.95 0.36 4.16 8.44]
 [3.65 9.61 8.76 3.18 8.12 7.95 0.36 4.16 8.44 9.99]
 [9.61 8.76 3.18 8.12 7.95 0.36 4.16 8.44 9.99 0.44]
 [8.76 3.18 8.12 7.95 0.36 4.16 8.44 9.99 0.44 5.24]
 [3.18 8.12 7.95 0.36 4.16 8.44 9.99 0.44 5.24 4.5 ]
 [8.12 7.95 0.36 4.16 8.44 9.99 0.44 5.24 4.5  9.63]]

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(xyz[0,:], indexer[0,:])
    plt.show()
```

[image: output of matplotlib (i.e. row 0 of xyz vz row 0 of indexer)]

Similarly, I am not getting the correct plots for subsequenct rows as well.

Where am I wrong in this?

Comment: Why are the plots not correct? What do you expect?

Comment: I mean if i actually plot the values, they don't come out the way the results are displayed on the matplotlib. the graphs obtained are incorrect, value wise. Thats why i even mentioned what values i took to plot a graph.